# How can I execute java code from plain text?

Tags: java, scripting

How can i execute java code from my java program? Is there a framework I could use to programatically execute them? please help, thanks.

My java class

```
public class test {

    public static compute(int one, int two){
         // compute goes here
   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //read from file
        //execute the commands
    }
}
```

my text file : contains java code fragments doesn't consists the whole java file.

```
   System.out.println("Start of my program");

@do("compute my two int"){
  val = compute(15,25);
  System.out.println(val);
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to test it? Are you using an IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: How can text file can call any java class.

Comment: @mdewitt thanks for the response. the java file is one time compiled to class. Only making changes to plain text file. and executing the java class file at runtime.

Comment: @user2115021 thanks for the comment, it's executed on command prompt
java test textfile.txt

Comment: If the plain file has the full class, you can use ProcessBuilder to compile and execute it.

Comment: @crnlx thanks for the note. I want plain file to be have more clarity.  and the class file have lot of functionality.

Comment: What I meant is, it can be a separate class from your calling class.

Comment: @crnlx is there any mechanism to parse the plain file? without recompile.

Comment: I'll recommend using Java Scripting Engine for this purpose instead  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html

Comment: @BrianRoach thanks for response. actually this is a code fragment of java on plain text not full class file.

Comment: Which means the answer is: You don't. At least not getting into runtime bytecode modification, which is extremely complex.

Comment: @karakfa wow!! it looks great! does it mean I can call java-script? or can this be modified to my purpose?

Comment: @karafka: Does it allow Java code also or does it allow only scripting languages?

Comment: Javascript is bundled with the distribution.  If you need proper Java syntax you can alternatively use BeanShell, which can be embedded in your application.  This essentially gives you an eval() method.

Answer (score 0):

The JDK contains the [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) API. You can use it to compile text to a .class file at runtime, and then proceed to make this file available on the classpath—and finally load it using reflection.

The above, if repeated, will result in a "class leak": all the classes you have ever loaded will be stuck in the runtime. To avoid that you'll need to create a new classloader for each class you load dynamically.